# Powershell GzipStream, "Cannot find an overload for "GZipStream" and the argument count: "2"

Tags: powershell, gzipstream

Trying to get GzipStream going in Posh. Have this:

```
[System.IO.MemoryStream] $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $output, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Optimal)
```

Getting error on the New-Object call:

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "GZipStream" and the argument
>   count: "2".

But the docs for the class show two constructors that take two arguments.
[GZipStream Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

"Optimal" is a member of the [CompressionLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=netframework-4.8) enum, not the [CompressionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionmode?view=netframework-4.8) enum, so your code should be:

```bsh
[System.IO.MemoryStream] $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream($output, [IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal)
```

In your particular case, PowerShell is trying to be helpful and converts non-existent enum member names to `$null`:

```bsh
PS> $null -eq [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Optimal
True

PS> $null -eq [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::NonExistentMember
True
```

so your original code is equivalent to:

```bsh
[System.IO.MemoryStream] $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $output, $null
```

which gives the same exception as you got. The error isn't so much that it can't find *a* constructor overload with 2 parameters, it's more that it found multiple suitable overloads and couldn't choose which one to use (see the first two constructors in [GZipStream Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)).

Note also that I had to wrap the constructor parameters in round brackets - this changes the way PowerShell resolves which constructor to call somehow. I'm not sure of the exact details, but using the round brackets makes it work!

```bsh
[System.IO.MemoryStream] $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream($output, [IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal)
```

Hope this helps.